# Javascript disable button with alert in content page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to prepare a small script that can disable button if input field is lower than number 1, and when the user presses the button while it is disabled he will get alert. Alert should be in content page, no popup. I prepared something like that:

```
<!-- language: lang-js --> 
var toValidate = $('#inputName, #inputEmail, #inputTel'),
valid = false;
toValidate.keyup(function () {
 if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
   $(this).data('valid', true);
 } else {
   $(this).data('valid', false);
}
toValidate.each(function () {
 if ($(this).data('valid') == true) {
   valid = true;
 } else {
 valid = false;
 }
});
 if (valid === true) {
  $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
 }else{
  $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);        
 }
});
```

This code works very well, but it only works if there is any value in the input field. I can enter 0 and validation is passed, also i can't modify the code to display alert text if user click on disable button.

Comment: just add alert('msg') in else part to alert box

Comment: It display message in pop, I want display text in content page, like normal text.

Comment: ok check my answer it will work your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="Button" />
<div></div>
```

here is CSS :

```
.disabled {
    background-color: #DDD;
    color: #999;
}
```

here is the script :

```
    function Validate(value) {
    if (value.length === 0) {
        $("input[type='submit']").addClass('disabled');
        return;
    } else $("input[type='submit']").removeClass('disabled');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='submit']").hasClass('disabled');

    $("input[type='text']").keyup(function () {
        Validate($("input[type='text']").val());
    });

    $("input[type='submit']").click(function () {
        Validate($("input[type='text']").val());
        if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) $("div").html("Alert msg");
        else return;
    });
});
```

Comment: @Megadevice : I fixed, take a try and let me know if it work for you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9asLF/ look, button is disable even if I type something in input field. When i clicked on button text doesnt appear.

Comment: I feel sorry about that, it's my by using onblur. Onblur is effect when you leave textbox then when you type in textbox, the code isn't activated.
then I use key up

Comment: don't worry and thanks for help, but there is still one bug. when i clicked on disable button text still does not appear. Could you help with fix it?

Comment: You can't click on disable button. Then I suggest that you can use CSS to make the button look like it was disabled.
When `validate = false` then     `$(input[type='button').addClass('disabled') `
and when `validate = true` then `$(input[type='button').removeClass('disabled')`
And with click event on the button, you can use condition :
`if($(this).hasClass('disabled') return; else { 'your code' }`

I will try and edit the code. Hope it can help you abit

Comment: I fixed it for you.
and take a look with new answer, it's good too

Comment: Great! Thank you very much, I will fit this peace of code for me, and it will be perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="vall" />
<input type="submit" id="btn" class="disabled" value="Button" />
<div></div>
```

**Script**

```
var value=$('#vall').val();

$("#vall").keyup(function(){

    if (value.length == 0) 
    {
      $("#btn").addClass('disabled');
        $("div").html("Fill Value");
    } 
    else 
        $("#btn").removeClass('disabled');
});
   $("#btn").click(function (){
        if (value.length == 0)
            $("div").html("Fill Value");
       else
           $("div").html("");
    });
```

**CSS**

```
.disabled, .btn[disabled] {
    background-image: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    cursor: default;
    opacity: 0.65;
}
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/9asLF/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my stab at it. I know it has already been answered... but I already did the work.

#### JSFIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/4JHy2/

#### HMTL

```
<ul class='errors' id='errors'></ul>

    <form id='myForm'>
        <label for'inputName'>Name:</label><br>
        <input type='text' id='inputName'>

        <br><br>

        <label for'inputEmail'>Email:</label><br>
        <input type='text' id='inputEmail'>

        <br><br>

        <label for'inputTel'>Telephone:</label><br>
        <input type='text' id='inputTel'>

        <br><br>

        <input type='submit' value='Submit' id='submit'>
    </form>
```

#### Javascript

```
var regExp = /^$|^ +$/,
        elements = [],
        eLength,
        formValid = false,
        errors;

    function clearErrors() { errors.html('') }

    function addError() { errors.append($('<li>Form disabled until all fields complete.</li>')) }

    $(function(){
        // Cache the form elements for performance and loopage.
        elements.push($('#inputName'));
        elements.push($('#inputEmail'));
        elements.push($('#inputTel'));
        eLength = elements.length;
        errors = $('#errors');

        // Listen for activity on all three elements.
        $('#inputName, #inputEmail, #inputTel').on('keyup', function(){
            // Clear previous errors.
            clearErrors();

            for(var i = 0; i < eLength; i++) {
                if (regExp.test($(elements[i]).val())) {
                    formValid = false;
                } else {
                    formValid = true;
                }
            }

            if (!formValid) { 
                addError();
            }
        });

        $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            // Clear previous errors.
            clearErrors();

            if (formValid) {
                alert("valid");
            } else {
                addError();
            }
        });
    });
```